# Combine two subject only when one changes and get latest from other

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

Im stuck getting the following example working as expected, I have tried using `zip` and `combineLatest` and as show below `withLatestFrom` however non of them gives the expected output.

```
@Test
fun thereCanBeOnlyOne() {
    val s1 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
    val s2 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()

    s2.withLatestFrom<Int, Int, Int>(s1)
            .subscribe { (a, b) ->
                println("$a - $b")
            }

    s1.onNext(1)
    s1.onNext(2)
    s2.onNext(1)
    s2.onNext(2)
    s1.onNext(333)
    s2.onNext(444)
}
```

What I want is the following to print:

> 2 - 1
>
> 2 - 2
>
> 333 - 444

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimenting I found the solution in:

```
@Test
fun thereCanBeOnlyOne() {
    val s1 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
    val s2 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()

        Observables.combineLatest(s1, s2)
            .distinctUntilChanged { (_,b) -> b }
            .subscribe { (a, b) ->
                println("$a - $b")
            }

    s1.onNext(1)
    s1.onNext(2)
    s2.onNext(1)
    s2.onNext(2)
    s1.onNext(333)
    s2.onNext(444)
}
```